# How many solutions $\pm1\pm2\pm3...\pm n=0$

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

As the title said, I'm very interested how many variants to choose $n$ signs from all $2^n$ variants when expression lead to zero. I tried to get recurrent formula but nothing happened.

Comment: It is 0 if $n$ gives remainder 1 or 2 modulo 4 (since such a sum would be odd). For $n$ congruent to 0 or 3 modulo $n$ it is the coefficient of $x^{n(n+1)/4}$ in the product $(1+x)(1+x^2)\dots (1+x^n)$. There is no known (or believed) general formula, but quite precise asymptotics.

Comment: Compute a few counts, enter a large one or two into OEIS, find http://oeis.org/A063865, and follow the references therein.  [In **gp**, using **Fedor Petrov**'s hint:  **for(n=0,40,if((n+1)%4<2,print([n,polcoeff(prod(m=1,n,1+x^m),(n^2+n)/4)])))** ]

Comment: The function $(1+x)(1+x^{2})\cdots(1+x^{n})$ is a modular function, and as such there's a Rademacher-type formula for its coefficients (which is even given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html)). So there is a "general" formula.

Comment: The *infinite* product $\prod_{m=1}^\infty (1+x^m)$ is a modular function.
The finite product $\prod_{m=1}^n (1+x^m)$ is not, and truncating the product
at the $n$th term reduces the $x^{(n^2+n)/4}$ coefficient once $n>3$,
so the Rademacher formula gives only an upper bound for the enumeration
that **Mr. Newman** asked for.

Comment: Thank you, men, for your answers! But what about $\pm1\pm3\pm5\pm...\pm(2n-1)$? Is this easier for getting general formula? Or it just lead to remove even powers from product above?

Comment: Probably about as intractable for getting exact answers,
though an asymptotic formula is again known.
Apparently this version is less studied: the same route, via
**for(n=1,20,print([n,polcoeff(prod(m=1,2*n,1+x^(2*m-1)),2*n^2)]))** ,
leads to https://oeis.org/A292476 and thence to https://oeis.org/A156700
but there's not nearly as much information there as there was on your
original question.